# Is ${\bf Z} \times {\bf Z}$ elementarily equivalent to ${\bf Z}$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider ${\bf Z}$ as a first-order structure in the language $\{0,+,-\}$ of abelian groups.

Is ${\bf Z} \times {\bf Z}$ elementarily equivalent to ${\bf Z}$ and why?

I think they are not elementarily equivalent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are not elementarily equivalent.

In ${\bf Z}$ we have 
$\exists x \forall y (\exists z (z + z = y \vee z + z + x = y))$

Namely, $x = 1$.

In ${\bf Z} \times {\bf Z}$, no such $x$ is possible.  Specifically, there are four classes (odd, odd), (even, even), (even, odd), and (odd, even), and no x covers the classes that aren't (even, even).